# How to use multiple XML ribbon in one Outlook VSTO Add in

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working with Outlook VSTO Add In and first I have added a Button(ribbon) to the TabMail  and after that I need a custom context menu item on right click any Inbox item, So I have added another Ribbon, but inside `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()` I can return only one Ribbon.

## Inside ThisAddIn.cs

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new Ribbon2();
}
```

I tried with some old unclear solution like below adding namespace, but it's not working,maybe they are for merging two tab and group but not for two different type ribbon.

## ContextMenuRibbon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" 
  onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns:x="MySpace.Outlook"> 
   <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
      <button
       id="MyContextMenuMailItem" label="ContextMenuMailItem" 
       idQ="MyRibbons"/>
   </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus> 
</customUI>
```

How can I use both Ribbon in same Add In?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide a single XML string with both elements specified in it.